# why binding checkedListBox needs so much time in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I Creative Sample Project and test checkedListBox DataSource to Binding,

and find it spends much time about 0.03 seconds.

I have 100 controls,so how can I reduce Binding Time.

Here is my Sameple code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<clsListItem> items = new List<clsListItem>();

                  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        items.Add( new clsListItem(){ Value= "01", Text=  "NYY"});
        items.Add(new clsListItem() { Value = "02", Text = "OAK" });
        items.Add(new clsListItem() { Value = "03", Text = "BAL" });

            watch.Start();
            ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DataSource = items;
            ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).DisplayMember = "Text";
            ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).ValueMember = "Value";
            watch.Stop();
            TimeSpan tt = watch.Elapsed;
            MessageBox.Show(tt.TotalSeconds.ToString());



    }
}

public class clsListItem {

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Lazy load the controls as they are needed.  You can also try not using `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.  Instead, override the `ToString()` method in the `clsListItem` class.

Comment: I try it override ToString() method in the clsListItem  class , just the same . About waste 0.03~0.04 seconds.

Comment: Try setting the DataSource property *last*, after setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.  Otherwise, having 100 CheckedListBox controls on the screen is just too many.  No user can, nor wants, to see that much information on the screen at once.  I would reconsider your user interface.

Comment: If possible, add to the object collection instead of binding to a DataSource: `((ListBox)checkedListBox1).Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());`  Should be around 0.0005 to 0.0007 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, add to the object collection instead of binding to a DataSource: ((ListBox)checkedListBox1).Items.AddRange(items.ToArray()); Should be around 0.0005 to 0.0007 seconds.